# Web scraping techniques to obtain links that the website of interest contains

Tags: r, web

I am working with the following website:
     http://www.crowdrise.com/skollsechallenge

Specifically on this page there are 57 crowdfunding campaigns.  Each of those crowdfunding campaigns have text that details out why they want to raise money, the total money raised so far, and the team members.  Some of the campaigns also specify the fundraising goal. I want to write some R code that will scrape and organize this information from each of the 57 sites.

for now, I am trying to scrap each of the 57 links that leads to the 57 different campaigns.
Below is the code I tried:

```
    library("RCurl")
    library("XML")
    library("stringr")

    url <- "http://www.crowdrise.com/skollSEchallenge"
    cat("URL:", url)
    url.data <- readLines(url) 
    doc <- htmlTreeParse(url.data, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
    xp_exp   <- "//a[@href]"
    links <- xpathSApply(doc, xp_exp,xmlValue)
```

the variable

```
     links
```

however, does not contain links to the 57 websites.....I am little confused...
can someone help me?

thanks,

Comment: if you search on stackoverflow for `[r] webcrawl` you will find lots of helpful questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this for example :

```
xpathApply(doc, '//*[@id="teams-results"]/div/div/div/h4/a'
           ,xmlGetAttr,'href')
```

You will get the 16 links of the first page. But you still have the problem of activating javascript code behind( SHOW MORE TEAMS) to see the rest of links.

Answer (score 0):

This very ugly solution gets 32 of them, it is very very verbose, but it does not need to evaluate javascript.

```
library(httr)
x <- as.character(GET("http://www.crowdrise.com/skollSEchallenge"))
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\n", fixed = TRUE))

x <- gsub("\t", "", grep('class="profile">', x, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = 'class="profile">', fixed = TRUE))[-1]

x <- gsub("\r<div class=\"content\">\r<a href=\"/", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
x <- substr(x, 1, as.integer(regexpr('\"><img', x)) - 1)
x <- paste("www.crowdrise.com/", x, sep = '')
```